# Render Page into Custom Output

Tags: asp.net, templates, rendering

Let´s take an usual aspx page, ~/admin/template.aspx

The admin folder allows only "Admin" roles for example.

Now I don´t want to run the template.aspx as usual, but I want it be called from a active process. 
Let´s say I´m on ~/admin/buildMyStuff.aspx and there I´m collecting some data, I now have some querystring, like "?do=this$andDo=that$index={0}". Now I want, using this template, loop through my data and generate my ouput, putting it then for example in a static html or in a text file or something else.

How should I do that? 
Calling it as new request, waiting for response? What I have to do, that it is running under the "Admin" role, or is it doing it automatically, since I already am admin?

Or is there another possibility, that allows me to run the template page and specifiing my custom htmltextwriter as output?

**EDIT:**

```
public static string RenderPageAndGetHtml(string pageUrl, string pageQuery)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest(pageUrl, pageQuery, sw);
        HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(wr);
        sw.Close();
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

This is the Solution.

**BUT:**

It seems that the SimpleWorkerRequest got a bug

following happens:

~/default.aspx Fails

/default.aspx  Fails

default.aspx Ok

en/default.aspx Fails

/en/default.aspx Fails

~/en/default.aspx Fails

EDIT:

Ok, i implemented my custom HttpWorkerRequest. Now it works...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the HTML Code of the template.aspx Page? Try this function, maybe that's what you need:

```
public static string RenderPageAndGetHtml(string pageUrl, string pageQuery)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest(pageUrl, pageQuery, sw);
        HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(wr);
        sw.Close();
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: that sounds like exactly this i was searching for. Is there anything I have to care about, some dependencies, like the httpcontext, is it going through the httpmodules? how looks the useridentity if i´m using your method?

Comment: hm, thats a good question - I'm not sure about it. I've used this function rarely and I'm not able to test it right now. It is either  the current ApplicationPool User or the Web User. Could you check it? Btw, I changed my answer because the Utf8WorkerRequest was a self-builded solution, you have to use the SimpleWorkerRequest.

Comment: seems not to work. the only way seems to be running this stuff through a new applicationhost, with ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost. But I don´t think it´s a good idea since it´s trying to load all my assemblies new.

Comment: when i´m using it without a new applicationhost, it throughs all the time file not found...

Comment: Hm. I'm sorry, I will take a look at the Utf8Worker tomorrow at work, maybe there are some special functions in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ine thing to note is that `SimpleWorkerRequest` doesn't take a url as input but path... i wasted a few hours on this, and it basically means that `en/default.aspx` will translate into

- page: en
- pathInfo: default.aspx

you need to use backslash as in a path

```
en\default.aspx
```

Comment: what? if that works, man... you wasted hours... man... me 2 days, and after that i´ve overwritten the whole damn worker... :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the UTF8WorkerRequest, but it was only for setting the SimpleWorkerRequest to UTF8 encoding (it's UTF16 internal). Sorry!

```
public class UTF8WorkerRequest : SimpleWorkerRequest 
{

    private TextWriter theWriter;

    public UTF8WorkerRequest(string page, string query, TextWriter output) : base(page, query, output)
    {
        theWriter = output;
    }

    public UTF8WorkerRequest(string appVirtualDir, string appPhysicalDir, string page, string query, TextWriter output) : base(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, page, query, output)
    {
        theWriter = output;
    }

    public override void SendResponseFromMemory(byte[] data, int length)
    {

        theWriter.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

    }
}
```